# Why is this polynomial unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring with $1$. For every $R$-Algebra $A$ we define $F_A: A^n \rightarrow A$ with the property that
>
> \begin{equation}\varphi(F_A(a_1,\ldots,a_n)) = F_B(\varphi(a_1),\ldots,\varphi(a_n)) \qquad (1)\end{equation}
>
> , where $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism between $R$-Algebras.
>
> Show that there is a unique polynomial $P \in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ such that $P_A = F_A$.

I understand that $P_A$ suffices the condition $(1)$, but $P \rightarrow P_A$ is in general not bijective, so our $P$ is not unique. I do not know what to do now. Could you please help me?

I have learned the following definitions:

> $R$-Algebra: Let $A$ and $R$ be rings. Then $A$ is called an $R$-Algebra if there exists a ring-homomorphism $s: R \rightarrow A$.
>
> $R$-Homomorphism: Let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-Algebras. A ring-homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ is called an $R$-homomorphism if $f \circ s_A = s_b$.
>
> ($P_A$ is the map $P_A:A^n \rightarrow A, a \mapsto P(a)$, where $P \in R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$)

Comment: Isn't $F_A$ defined for *all* $R$-algebras $A$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will make an edit.

Comment: If yes, you can choose $A:=R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and set $P:=F_A(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but why can we be sure that $P$ is then indeed unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we might not be able to recover the polynomial of a single function $R^n\to R$, however the assumption includes all $R$-algebras.

Consider $A:=R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.
The trick is that, for any polynomial $P\in A$, if we substitute the elements $X_i\in A$ by themselves, we obtain
$$P_A(X_1,\dots,X_n)=P$$
which shows exactly how we can uniquely recover a polynomial.

So if $F_A=P_A$ (still for this particular $A$) for some polynomial $P$, then by the above, we must have
$$P=F_A(X_1,\dots,X_n)\,.$$
To see then $F_B=P_B$ holds for any $R$-algebra $B$, just use the hypothesis and that $R$-algebra homomorphisms from the polynomial ring $A$ correspond exactly to the *evaluations* of $X_i$.